# Make this repetitive statement into a loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This Code is too repetitive! I have to re write this code up to twenty! Can you guys help me covert this into a loop that wil just move from textbox1, to 2 to 3 and so on?

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
        frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
        frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckBox2.Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End If        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
        frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
        frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckBox2.Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
    If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
        frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
        frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckBox3.Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
    If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
        frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
        frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckBox4.Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
    If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
        frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
        frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckBox5.Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
```

This works, thanks for the help guys, the issue was the direct cast. Solved:

```
Public Class frmBeverages
Dim Range As Integer = 0
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    While Range < 14
        Range = Range + 1
        Dim chk As CheckBox =
        DirectCast(Me.Controls("Checkbox" & CStr(Range)), CheckBox)
        If chk.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber = frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber + 1
            frmLunchBoxMenu.txtOrder.AppendText(CStr(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber) & ".) An order of " & chk.Text & Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    End While
    Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Well I had a method but it just wasn't working, I could post that instead if you like.

Comment: where is this code located at, is it in a eventhandler or a subroutine ?

Comment: Very good beginning programmer's question +1

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Use arrays (or other structures) to cut down on variables. That should reduce code duplication in one swoop.

Comment: Ok guys, I used a while statement and just looped it, this is what I wanted, Thanks

Comment: For i = 1 To 20
    If CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i.ToString), TextBox).Checked = True then
 'Statements here
Next

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim strOutput As String = ""
Dim intLineNumber As Integer = 0
For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf ctl Is CheckBox Then
    Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox)
    If chk.Checked Then
      intLineNumber += 1
      strOutput &= intLineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + ctl.Text & vbCrLf
    End If
  End If
Next ctl
txtOrder.Text = strOutput
```

...but you should also consider using the CheckedListBox control instead. That will allow your menu to be dynamically loaded (loaded from a text file or a database), and you won't need to manage multiple checkbox controls.

Here's the CheckedListBox version...

```
Public Class frmLunchBoxMenu
  'Add a CheckedListBox, a Button, and a TextBox named txtOrder to the form
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Hamburger")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Pizza")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Cola")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Chips")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Hot dog")
  End Sub


  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strOutput As String = ""
    Dim intLineNumber As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
      If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) Then
        intLineNumber += 1
        strOutput &= intLineNumber.ToString + ".) An order of " + CheckedListBox1.Items(i).ToString & vbCrLf
      End If
    Next i
    txtOrder.Text = strOutput
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Dynamically loaded? What is that?

Comment: I meant you can load your menu from a text file or a database when the application is running, so you don't need to recompile every time the menu changes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way to do it:

```
    Dim Range As Integer() =
        Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray

    For Each n As Integer In Range

        Dim chk As CheckBox =
            DirectCast(Me.Controls("Checkbox" & CStr(n)), CheckBox) 
        ' Specify above the right ControlCollection if needed.

        If chk.Checked Then

            With frmLunchBoxMenu
                .LineNumber += 1
                .txtOrder.AppendText(CStr(frmLunchBoxMenu.LineNumber) &
                                     ".) An order of " & chk.Text &
                                     Environment.NewLine)
            End With

        End If

    Next n
```